# Partition pruning not working on Hudi dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

We have created a Hudi dataset which has two level partition like this

```
s3://somes3bucket/partition1=value/partition2=value
```

where `partition1` and `partition2` is of type `string`

When running a simple `count` query using `Hudi` format in `spark-shell`, it takes almost 3 minutes to complete

```scala
spark.read.format("hudi").load("s3://somes3bucket").
  where("partition1 = 'somevalue' and partition2 = 'somevalue'").
  count()

res1: Long = ####

attempt 1: 3.2 minutes
attempt 2: 2.5 minutes
```

Here is also the metrics in Spark UI where ~9000 tasks (which is approximately equivalent to the total no of files in the **ENTIRE** dataset `s3://somes3bucket`) are used for computation. Seems like spark is reading the entire dataset instead of **partition pruning**....and then filtering the dataset based on the `where` clause

[image]

Whereas, if I use the `parquet` format to read the dataset, the query only takes ~30 seconds (vis-a-vis 3 minutes with Hudi format)

```scala
spark.read.parquet("s3://somes3bucket").
  where("partition1 = 'somevalue' and partition2 = 'somevalue'").
  count()

res2: Long = ####

~ 30 seconds
```

Here is the spark UI, where only 1361 files are scanned (vis-a-vis ~9000 files in Hudi) and takes only 15 seconds [image]

Any idea why partition pruning is not working when using `Hudi` format? Wondering if I am missing any configuration during the creation of the dataset?

PS: I ran this query in `emr-6.3.0` which has Hudi version `0.7.0`

Comment: What did you figure out with this?

Comment: @Dude0001 we have upgraded to the latest Hudi version. No issues now